# Mysql : Products which satisfies category conditions

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

I want only those products which satisfies following condition :

Which have `((category_id = 1 OR category_id = 2) AND (category_id = 3 OR category_id = 4))`

Database structure:

**products**

```
id  int(10)     
name    varchar(128)
```

**categories**

```
Id  int (10)
name    varchar(64)
```

**category_products**

```
product_id  int(10)
category_id int(10)
```

Data:

My product details are:

```
Products:
id  name
1   P1
2   P2
3   P3
4   P4
```

My category details are:

```
Categories:
Id  name
1   C1
2   C2
3   C3
4   C4
```

My category-product mapping details are:

```
category_products:
product_id   category_id
1            1
1            3
1            4
2            2
3            1
3            2
3            3
3            4
4            1
4            4   



Final Output should be:
    id
    1
    3
    4
```

Comment: Does the clause make sense ? `category_id IN (1,2,3,4)` ?

Comment: Do you have a query that you have started? What is your desired fields? Can you post a sample of your desired outcome?

Comment: are you sure that all are `category_id` in your condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN category_products AS c1 ON c1.product_id=p.id
INNER JOIN category_products AS c2 ON c2.product_id=p.id
WHERE c1.category_id IN (1,2) AND c2.category_id IN (3,4)
```

It wouldn't work to use

```
WHERE c.category_id IN (1,2) AND c.category_id IN (3,4)
```

because a WHERE clause tests just one row at a time, and there's no way one category_id can have two values on a single row.  So the self-join handles that, by matching more than one row and referencing them by correlation names.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking..! Currently there are only two AND conditions but In real time I have around 10 "AND" conditions!

Comment: Then you'll have to do 10 self-joins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to optimize this query..?(Instead of 10 self-joins)

Comment: This *is* the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
select * 
from products 
where id in (select distinct(product_id) 
             from category_products 
             where (category_id =3 0R category_id=4) 
               AND (category_id =1 OR category_id=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.product_id AS id FROM product_categories AS p
WHERE (p.category_id=1 OR p.category_id=2) AND (p.category_id=3 OR p.category_id=4) GROUP BY p.category_id
```

Because you don't need the name of the product you don't need an INNER JOIN. GROUP BY and DISTINCT should both work.

Comment: Check out solution by : Bill Karwin